# Powershell - Import-CSV gives out empty arrays

Tags: csv, powershell, import

I've got the following problem:

Whenever I import a .csv file, I can't use the header array elements correctly.

Example:

```
$data = Import-CSV data.csv
```

Now, trying to access the data with `$data.Surname` or whatever, is just empty. Giving out `$data` in general displays all the information from the csv file. Does anyone know what the problem is here?

Comment: Is this PowerShell 2.0?

Comment: It's Powershell 4.0

Comment: Does this give the same problem? `$data | ForEach-Object { $_.Surname }`

Comment: That actually worked, thanks. Still got a problem though. Farther through my script, I want to enable newly created ad users. But the recently created ones can't be found via `Get-ADUser`, even though it is existing in the ad

Comment: That's a shame, I was hoping it wouldn't work, it'd suggest the header has extra characters (trailing white space). Ah well. As for AD, Get-ADUser, like any directory search, is subject to replication time if you have an extended topology. Relevant?

Comment: Unfortunately not, I am trying this in a testing environment on the very dc

Comment: I want to add that the user login names all look like this: 12345789-01@domain.de, if that matters. Trying to use `Get-ADUser "123456789-01"` (with or without quotation marks) doesn't work

Comment: Another extra: Searching for all users with `Get-ADUser -Filter *` displays the users I can't find individually

Comment: "*Whenever I import a .csv file*" - then the problem can't be with your csv format, or with character encoding, because it would only happen on some files. It must be your PS profile, e.g. you've overwritten `Import-CSV` with something else, or you've got a corrupt PowerShell install ... or you're being hyperbolic and it's misleading. Probably that, eh. If I had to throw a wild guess, your problem is elsewhere in your script mangling the data somehow. Can you edit into your question some example lines from the CSV and some code which demonstrates what behaviour you see? [mcve]

Comment: Problem solved: the samaccountname was created with @domain.de at the end, which provided the error. thanks for all the input!